# Cartoon where they used sand timer looking things to summon monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember there being different coloured ones and there was a teen with white hair and tanned skin I think he had a blue one and his was like a polar bear looking thing.

Comment: This is very vague. Please take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) and [edit] in any more details you remember. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

#### [*Monsuno*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1579911/) (2011)

> The series revolves around re-awakened Monster DNA, called Monsuno, that finds its way into the unsuspecting hands of adventure-seeking teenagers Chase, Jinja, and Bren. Accompanied by their Monsuno, Lock, Charger, and Quickforce, they are searching for Chase's father Jeredy Suno, the creator of the Monsuno. They are soon joined by Beyal, a monk from the Himalayas along with his Monsuno Glowblade. Beyal often speaks of five people that with the help of their Monsuno, could change the world. It just so happens that they are that five, along with Dax, a teenager who along with his Monsuno Airswitch, opposes the team and is disliked among most people. The team has yet to befriend him and persuade him to join their cause. They are also on the run from an agency called "S.T.O.R.M." (Strategic Tactical Operatives for Recovery of Monsuno) who's plans are still in question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should add information to your answer to show how it matches the details of the question.  Please read [answer].